# Does extra SQL filtering improve or worsen performance

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's say I'm trying to search for products by name in a SQL database. I can do so by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name='Chair';
```

I know I can speed up this query by creating an Index on the name column. Would filtering on another key speed it up even further? Or would it make it worse?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE type="Office Supplies" and name='Chair';
```

I would guess they're about the same.

Comment: Yes, adding an index would probably help.

Comment: No, if `name='Chair'` is subset of `type="Office Supplies"`

Comment: Yes, `Chair` is a subset of `Office Supplies`. So it hurts performance or does nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the second `WHERE` condition is redundant in your comment. In that case, it is bound to hurt, perhaps not much.

At the very least, the database has to spend some cycles on an unnecessary extra test for no gain.

In the mid range of fallout, you may use a two-column index to support the query. Such an index is larger, so it wastes disk space and is more expensive to scan.

In the worst case, the database will assume that the two conditions are statistically independent when they are not and will badly underestimate the result count. If your query is part of a bigger query, that could lead to bad plan choices further down the line.

Conclusion: don't make your queries more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an index as follows

```
create index range_scan on products (name);
```

and then following command to display lines

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = 'Chair';
```

range scan will be used.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1542557660
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |     1 |     4 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| EMP_MGR |     1 |     4 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
```

When you add a new attribute to the select, the range scan will not be used.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2418964722
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |       |    14 |   140 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | E_CIX |    14 |   140 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead of the **range scan index**, the **full scan index** was used after adding a new attribute to the selection.

Comment: Any time, have a nice day.